# Which Android components are needed to implement a swiping picture strip?

Tags: android, android-widget, swipe

I am trying to implement a picture gallery with swipe. I want to have the current image take up the whole screen, and have a single row of all images overlaid on the bottom of the screen. Navigation would occur by either swiping the current image (go to next or previous image), or swiping the little gallery and selecting an image from it.

What component(s) (that can hold a single row of images and is swipable) could I use for the gallery?